# How to format the DateTimePicker into hh:mm:ss and What is the appropriate type to save time in mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net, datetimepicker

I want to save the time in the format hh:mm:ss from the DateTimePicker to MySQL database, How to format the DateTimePicker into hh:mm:ss only without date and What is the appropriate type to save time in mysql?

Regards & Thanks,

Putri Diana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format it to show time by

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "hh:mm:ss";
dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Get the value into a Timespan object in this way for processing in your code

```
TimeSpan ts1 = TimeSpan.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Text);
```

I think MySql has got a Time Datatype you could use that (Ahh Got this [here](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-time.php))

Comment: thanks. I get this error message at the MsgBox line:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible